# Unable to Connect to Raspberry Pi with SSH

Tags: pi-3b+, troubleshooting

My Raspberry Pi is active on my network and I confirmed that it's online with an IP scanner. But if I run PuTTY (I usually connect through SSH instead of HDMI) and try to connect, it says that the hostname doesn't exist. Is this a problem with my Raspberry Pi or something else?

Comment: something else (local DNS issue)... your pi has an IP address, use that to connect ssh

Comment: Thanks, @JaromandaX ! It worked!

Comment: what sort  of computer/operating system are you using to connect to the pi - perhaps I can help with "not accessible using hostname" issue you have

Comment: Please make an answer and explain in short how you have solved the problem. This will finish the question and show others that it as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Jaromanda X. My problem is now solved by using an IP address instead of the hostname. I'm using Windows 10 with PuTTY to connect to the Raspberry Pi, in answer to your OS question.